# Cloth simulation's Dynamic mesh option is not working

Tags: animation, blender

So I'm new in blender and I'm just trying to do a simple animation that involves a cloth going towards a cube and sweeping it off a plane. The thing is, I want the base mesh to move with the cloth animation/shader(idk how it works) and I thought that the dynamic mesh option under shape/cloth would work but it doesn't. What do I do?
[Preview of the animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzSx7.png)
[Settings for the cloth which is a cloth btw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW8gk.png)

I was expecting the base mesh to move with the animation of the cloth.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think blende allows cloth and rigid bodies at the same time on one object. But I solved it like this:

1. Make plane and cube one object
   [image: step1]
2. Add A vertex group called pin with these Vertices
   [image: step2]
3. Add a empty at the middle vertex and add a hook modifier to the plane+cube object and set the empty as hook

[image: step3]

4. Copy these settings and animate the empty and you're done!
   [image: step4]

download the blend file [here](https://uploadnow.io/f/XKXk1mm) (3.3.8)